# Eclipse Show blank messages in Logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat, eclipse-mars

I have upgraded my eclipse from Luna to Mars 5.1. After upgrading eclipse it didn't show logs in logcat. Instead of this it shows a blank log screen.

Comment: google don't support anymore eclipse for android, why don't use android studio?

Answer (score 0):

You should be having an option to open **DDMS** view.

In that you will shown a list of **Devices**. Your connected device will appear here (make sure your device is connected and its USB driver is installed and detected by Eclipse). Double click on it. Logcat should appear then.